# What was the sound on the bridge when Q showed up after being stripped of his powers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Deja Q," Q is made human and transported to the Enterprise. Just prior to his arrival, an unusual noise is heard on the bridge, which neither Data nor Worf can identify.

Does anything state what this noise was? Was it a "portal" opening from the Q Continuum to the normal space-time continuum?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/161.txt) isn't especially helpful. I've edited out the dialogue.

> In the background, a strange noise... it begins low... more like a
>   million voices than a million machines... It gets louder... The sound
>   continues to grow... and seems to surround the ship... they react...
>   almost deafening now... The sound swirling inside and all around...
>   ends with a slight POP. Q APPEARS, naked, suspended above everyone, as
>   though held by an invisible puppet.

In context, it would appear to be the sound a Q makes when you forcibly remove their powers, turn them into a human, strip them [buck naked](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/61298840.jpg) and shove them headfirst through a space hole.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - I'm judging you for clicking it :-)

Comment: Held by an invisible *puppet* ??   They were on funny beans that day!  What exactly is it like being held by a puppet?  And why was Q held by one?!

Comment: Invisible puppet is a great name for a band

Comment: It's clearly meant to be *held like a puppet* or *held by an invisible puppeteer*